# Why form-recognizer returned "boundingBox" coordinates seem incorrect for my PDF form?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I'm using form-recognizer to extract text information from a sample PDF form (ACORD 3101 (2012/02)), but the returned "boundingBox" on some fields seem incorrect to me. I am wondering what's the reason behind it.

1. Please instruct how those boundingBox information are calculated. Thanks.
2. Please see the returned json response. The "key-value" pairs are not as expected, either. There is a "Token" key comes with multiple values. But actually each of those values should under their own key. Why?

I had trained the services by using multiple filled forms and one empty one. When I call "/{id}/keys" on the trained model, I did see the keys being identified:

```
{
  "clusters": {
    "0": ["ADDITIONAL REMARKS", "ADDITIONAL REMARKS SCHEDULE", "Effective Date:", "Form Number:", "Form Title:", "Insured", "Insurer", "Intermediary", "Page", "Policy Number", "This Additional Remarks form is a schedule to ACORD form,", "__Tokens__"]
  }
}
```

It looks fine to me. Then I called the "/{id}/analyze" API to extract a sample PDF. The result, as I said, seems incorrect. Below is part of the Json response I got.

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "pages": [
        {
            "number": 1,
            "height": 842,
            "width": 595,
            "clusterId": 0,
            "keyValuePairs": [
                {
                    "key": [
                        {
                            "text": "Page",
                            "boundingBox": [
                                493.2,
                                811.6,
                                514.7,
                                811.6,
                                514.7,
                                801.6,
                                493.2,
                                801.6
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "value": [
                        {
                            "text": "of",
                            "boundingBox": [
                                543.6,
                                811.6,
                                552.1,
                                811.6,
                                552.1,
                                801.6,
                                543.6,
                                801.6
                            ],
                            "confidence": 1.0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key": [
                        {
                            "text": "__Tokens__",
                            "boundingBox": [
                                0.0,
                                0.0,
                                0.0,
                                0.0,
                                0.0,
                                0.0,
                                0.0,
                                0.0
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "value": [
                        {
                            "text": "1",
                            "boundingBox": [
                                62.3,
                                97.3,
                                62.8,
                                97.3,
                                62.8,
                                96.2,
                                62.3,
                                96.2
                            ],
                            "confidence": 0.24
                        },
                        {
                            "text": "1",
                            "boundingBox": [
                                66.6,
                                97.3,
                                67.1,
                                97.3,
                                67.1,
                                96.2,
                                66.6,
                                96.2
                            ],
                            "confidence": 0.24
                        },
                        {
                            "text": "John Doe",
                            "boundingBox": [
                                2.8,
                                93.9,
                                6.9,
                                93.9,
                                6.9,
                                92.8,
                                2.8,
                                92.8
                            ],
                            "confidence": 0.24
                        },
                        {
                            "text": "Taren Liu",
                            "boundingBox": [
                                36.4,
                                93.8,
                                40.4,
                                93.8,
                                40.4,
                                92.8,
                                36.4,
                                92.8
                            ],
                            "confidence": 0.24
                        },
                        {
                            "text": "23456R02",
                            "boundingBox": [
                                2.8,
                                90.8,
                                7.2,
                                90.8,
                                7.2,
                                89.8,
                                2.8,
                                89.8
                            ],
                            "confidence": 0.24
                        },
                        {
                            "text": "RBA",
                            "boundingBox": [
                                2.8,
                                87.9,
                                4.7,
                                87.9,
                                4.7,
                                86.9,
                                2.8,
                                86.9
                            ],
                            "confidence": 0.24
                        },
                        {
                            "text": "11/08/2019",
                            "boundingBox": [
                                48.2,
                                87.9,
                                53.0,
                                87.9,
                                53.0,
                                86.9,
                                48.2,
                                86.9
                            ],
                            "confidence": 0.24
                        },
                        {
                            "text": "140001",
                            "boundingBox": [
                                10.4,
                                83.3,
                                13.6,
                                83.3,
                                13.6,
                                82.2,
                                10.4,
                                82.2
                            ],
                            "confidence": 0.24
                        },
                        {
                            "text": "Hello World",
                            "boundingBox": [
                                22.6,
                                83.3,
                                27.5,
                                83.3,
                                27.5,
                                82.2,
                                22.6,
                                82.2
                            ],
                            "confidence": 0.24
                        },
                        {
                            "text": "This is the second fake form. See",
                            "boundingBox": [
                                2.8,
                                80.9,
                                17.0,
                                80.9,
                                17.0,
                                79.8,
                                2.8,
                                79.8
                            ],
                            "confidence": 0.24
                        },
                        {
                            "text": "if",
                            "boundingBox": [
                                17.3,
                                80.9,
                                17.8,
                                80.9,
                                17.8,
                                79.8,
                                17.3,
                                79.8
                            ],
                            "confidence": 0.24
                        },
                        {
                            "text": "the form recognizer can learn from this.",
                            "boundingBox": [
                                18.0,
                                80.9,
                                34.7,
                                80.9,
                                34.7,
                                79.8,
                                18.0,
                                79.8
                            ],
                            "confidence": 0.24
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "tables": []
        }
    ],
    "errors": []
}
```

Please notice the height and width values (842 and 595 respectively) are correct. These are normal A4 paper size in points. However, fields of "John Doe" and "aren Liu" are having incorrect boundingBox information. Clearly those boundingBoxes are gathered at the lower-left corner of the paper (e.g. for "John Doe" they are 2.8, 93.9, 6.9, 93.9, 6.9, 92.8, 2.8, 92.8), not the expected location at the top of the pdf. Why?

[Here is the sample pdf used for both training and analyzing](https://forformrecognizer.blob.core.windows.net/charles/complex-2.pdf?sp=r&st=2019-08-07T15:58:53Z&se=2020-08-07T23:58:53Z&spr=https&sv=2018-03-28&sig=WzuTXVMfp0UxwLPVMjROjb8SyFGhtH%2By%2ByARGWJIcV0%3D&sr=b)

[Here is another sample pdf used for training](https://forformrecognizer.blob.core.windows.net/charles/second3101.pdf?sp=r&st=2019-08-07T17:46:35Z&se=2020-08-08T01:46:35Z&spr=https&sv=2018-03-28&sig=rg36DAOuepofgzulNdcNIIq3GLhXU3oRT%2BSOtz%2BZKt4%3D&sr=b)

[Here is the empty pdf used for training](https://forformrecognizer.blob.core.windows.net/charles/empty.pdf?sp=r&st=2019-08-07T17:32:32Z&se=2020-08-08T01:32:32Z&spr=https&sv=2018-03-28&sig=jdHY6mmmfc6VPYmeNjLajgrv8UfqsMDaeNWtmR1Wvzc%3D&sr=b)

Answer (score 1):

1. Bounding boxes - The 8 numbers represent 4 pairs of (x,y) coordinates of the bounding box corners in the following order: top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left. The origin of the coordinates system is the bottom left of the page.
2. The key "**Token**" includes all the text that Form Recognizer did not match to key value pairs or tables.

Can you please share also the training data anonymized without any real data ?

Comment: Thank you. 1 - Yes I understand the coordinates. But if you look at the returned bounding boxes' coordinates, the numbers are obviously incorrect. Actually, based on the returned coordinates, all the values under "Token" are grouped together at the lower-left corner, which is wrong.

Comment: 2 - OK. But why those values don't match key? When I look at the keys of the trained model, they look correct. Keys are there.

Comment: I edited the question, uploaded all the files. Two are sample filled forms and one empty form. The first sample file is also used for the analyzing test. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thanks looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify that these boundingboxes where correct?